# Send Login and Geolocation (from javascript) to Server

Tags: javascript, php

I have a standard HTML form that submits login data to a server, but I would also like to submit the users geolocation from javascript.I use the geolocation code from another stackoverflow question:

```
window.onload = function(){
if(navigator.geolocation)
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handlesucces, onError);
}

 function handlesucces(location) {
location.coords.latitude;
location.coords.longitude;
 }

 function onError() {
document.write("Error");
}
```

But am unsure how to add this data to the POST from the HTML form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML :

```
<form method=POST action="/script.php">
Username : <input type=text name=user>
Password : <input type=password name=pass>
<input type=hidden id=latitude name=latitude>
<input type=hidden id=longitude name=longitude>
<button type=submit>Submit</button>
```

This is an example login form that POSTs data to "/script.php" and also has two hidden fields which will have the location data (set by the JS below).

Javascript :

```
function handlesucces(location) {
    document.getElementById("latitude").value = location.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById("longitude").value = location.coords.longitude;
}
```

This function should replace the `handlesucces` function in your original code; it sets the two hidden fields of the form defined above with the location data.